# How to efficiently update a collection of paths through a graph after adding edges to the graph?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, functional-programming, graph-theory

My application may be modeled as a rooted, oriented multidigraph with possible parallel arcs and one distinguished source but with no loops or cycles.

The primary features of the application are a subset of the possible paths induced by the graph. That is, at some level, a better model for the application may be instead a rooted star digraph with no parallel arcs such that each arc represents a root-emanating path in the former multidigraph.

Let (f : Rooted-Multidigraphs -> Star-Digraphs) be the reclassification that interprets any root-emanating path (not necessarily terminating at a leaf) as a distinct arc.

Let (g : Star-Digraphs -> Star-Digraphs) be a series of arbitrary filters that prunes all domain-invalid arcs from a star digraph.

Then, although my application relies on data that constitutes a multigraph G, the application is primarily responsible for reporting features associated with star-graph T = g(f(G)).

Moreover, should any modifications occur to G -- specifically, arc deletions and additions -- with G becoming G', then the collection of valid paths must also be updated to T' = g(f(G')).

Say, for example, modifications d0*, d1* remove arcs #0 and #1, respectively, from a graph; modifications d2 and d3 add arcs #2 and #3 to a graph; and, overall, modification d successively applies d0*, d1*, d2, and d3 in some unspecified order.

If the filter g doesn't remove any path along a newly added arc (like #2 and #3 above), are there any efficient non-mutating methods (persistent data structures like radix trees, e.g., or functional-programming algorithms) for determining the updated target graph T' = g(f(d(G)) from just

- G
- T = g(f(G))
- deleted arcs {#0, #1}
- added arcs {#2, #3}

without directly applying either g or the composite function (g.f)?

Comment: How do you know the filter `g` doesn't remove any path along the newly added arcs if not by applying it?

Comment: Shouldn't `T' = T + f(d(G)) - f(G)`?

Comment: @Bergi, that seems right. However, I also hope to minimize the costs of applying f and determining set-theoretical unions and differences (even though I didn't mention these restrictions above).

Comment: I've been trying to break the problem into smaller, more manageable parts. My approach so far has been something like the following: Let [e] represent the subgraph comprising all edges of all appropriate paths along edge e. Then, if d'(G) = G + {e}, f(d'(G)) = f(G) + f([e]). Moreover, [e]  can be decomposed into subgraphs E0, {e}, E1, and then f([e]) would be f(E0) * {e} * (paths in E1).

Comment: However, if I try an approach suggested by my previous comment, an accounting system tracking all preceding/succeeding subgraphs for every edge (or maybe node instead) might be needed. And I've been struggling to find an efficient way to manage this accounting system when edge deletions also occur.

Comment: So far, my research has pointed me down two different paths: (1) some kind of comonadic representation of graphs (akin to the fgl library) where each edge/node somehow contains the the paths that traverse it; and (2) radix/patricia/prefix trees that let me swap "successor" subgraphs (incident to an edge being added) for the "successor" subgraphs to edges being deleted. I haven't gotten either approach to work yet, though, and maybe neither can. Thus my posting here.